# nwjs - call function on binary file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

```
// source.js
function foo(){
    alert("its work!");
}

// main.js
nw.Window.open("index.html", {}, function (win) {});
setTimeout(() => {
  let win = nw.Window.get();
  win.evalNWBin(null, "binary.bin");
  foo();
}, 2000);
```

i run follow command to generate binary file:

```
nwjc source.js binary.bin
```

and when i run above code it shows this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

how can I call function on binary.bin from main js?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing `"main": "index.js"` in your `package.json`, the code will run in the Node context and `alert` is not a function.

If you instead do `"main": "index.html"` then have

```html
<script>
  nw.Window.get().evalNWBin(null, 'binary.bin');
  foo();
</script>
```

it will work fine.

You can `Right-Click > Inspect Background Page` to see the node process dev tools for console log errors.

Alternatively, you can expose your function on the global `window` object.

```js
window.foo = function () {
  alert('It works');
};
```

And you can wait for the App Window to load by putting your code in the callback function.

```js
nw.Window.open('index.html', {}, function (win) {
  win.evalNWBin(null, 'binary.bin');
  win.window.foo();
});
```

Then you don't need to "get" the window, you already have it. And you can access its global `window` object to reach stuff stored on it.